# Extracting pattern from log file in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a log file from which I want to **extract only two patterns repeating multiple times**

> ChannelRequestDailyLog.log.2015-06-05: INFO [Thread-9290]
>   (ChannelRequestDailyLog.java:174) -  ::
>   [IID:11][RNW:TR][RQRVT:1433477166808][RQLGT:1433477167203][RQID:4945][STV:RC][RQST:USSD][RQS:USSD][RQEXT:1433477167203][SUID:TRNP0000185881][SUN:727862315][SC:New
>   POS][SM:727862315][SNW:TR]**[TID:R150605.0606.110013]**[TS:200][E:null][RM:728128482][AMT:100][SST:1][RID:INTID00016]**[VAL:49**][TOP:0][COS:0][PROMO:0][TOPENQ:0][PROMOENQ:0][COSENQ:0][POSTVAL:0][PPT:346][RTT:395]

Pattern that I want to see are `TID: and VAL: along with the text after ":".`

Comment: So, what's the problem – or do you just want us writing your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use perl:

```
my $string =  <STDIN>;
chomp $string;
@arr = $string =~ /\[((?:TID|VAL):[\w.]*)\]/g;
$arr_len = scalar @arr;
for ( $i=0; $i<$arr_len; $i=$i+1){
    print "$arr[$i]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
TID:R150605.0606.110013
VAL:49
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Perl regex with grep:**

`TID`:

```
grep -oP "(?<=\[)TID:[^:]*(?=\])" filepath
```

Output:

```
TID:R150605.0606.110013
```

`VAL`:

```
grep -oP "(?<=\[)VAL:[^:]*(?=\])" filepath
```

Output:

```
VAL:49
```

**If you want to get both (TID and VAL) at once, then:**

```
grep -oP "(?<=\[)(TID|VAL):[^:]*(?=\])" filepath
```

Note: Assumed there won't be any `:` after `TID:` and closing `]`